# How to read military hour '00' as '24' in Date.TryParseExact using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I need to get list of files from a folder that matches the file pattern and date format of each file name. The date format is yyyyMMdd HHmm, so if the file pattern is 'test_', the system must get all files containing file names like 'test_20150105 2100'.

I used DateTime.TryParseExact to check if the date matches with the given date format.

My problem is the system can't able to get the file if the hour in the file name is '2400'.

Below is the code I used which works good only for those file names without '2400' hour:

```
    Dim find As String = "test_"
    Dim last As Char
    Dim length, n As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim dformat As String = "yyyyMMdd HHmm"
    Dim extractedDate As String
    Dim ddt As DateTime
    Dim filename As String

    For Each file As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\JGC\shared folder test")

        filename = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)

        length = filename.Length

        If filename.Contains(find) Then

            last = find(find.Length - 1)
            n = find.LastIndexOf(last) + 1

            extractedDate = filename.Substring(n, length - find.Length)

            If DateTime.TryParseExact(extractedDate, dformat, Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, ddt) Then

                value = find & extractedDate

                If filename = value Then

                    ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file))

                End If

            End If

        End If

    Next
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `24:00` isn't really a valid 24-hour time, it should go from `23:59:59` to `00:00:00`.

Comment: @Dai Sir is there any other function that validates if the string matches with a given date format?

Comment: @Dai `24:00` in fact **is** a valid 24-hour time, [see this explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Midnight_00:00_and_24:00). But it is not recognized by .NET. It denotes that the time should belong as end of the day to the given date.

Comment: @abto my apologies, I stand corrected. Apparently ISO 8601 does allow "24:00" to denote the end of a day.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a special-case for "2400":

```
if( extractedDate.EndsWith("2400") ) {
    extractedDate = extractedDate.SubString( 0, extractedDate.Length - 4) + " 2359";
}

if( DateTime.TryParseExact( extractedDate, ...
```